# tcpdump: Does DNS traffic on eth0 indicate that VPN is improperly configured?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, dns, firewall

I ran `tcpdump -ni eth0 port 53` and `tcpdump -ni openvpn port 53`, to see if DNS information was being routed through my normal internet connection or my OpenVPN service.

I am running `transmission-daemon`, and I was surprised that the monitoring of `eth0` showed traffic to a torrent tracker, while `openvpn` did not display any traffic on port `53` at all.

```
$ tcpdump -ni eth0 port 53

XX:XX:XX.XXXXXX IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 21651, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 94)
    192.168.0.1.53 > 192.168.0.15.XXXXX: XXXXX 2/0/0 bt.xxxxx.com. A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, bt.xxxxx.com. A XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (66)
```

Does this imply that my "real" IP address is leaking to the tracker, or does it simply mean that `eth0` is what's being used to transport the `openvpn` traffic?

When using this *[TorGuard IP test torrent](https://torguard.net/checkmytorrentipaddress.php)* in my Torrent application, it displays the correct VPN IP address – not my original one.

I have set up a firewall script to bind the VPN to use the port `24328` for BitTorrent traffic (which I can also see when I monitor that port). My thinking is that the tracker could be sending other types of requests via other ports than `24328`, and that traffic goes via the normal interface `eth0` to the tracker?

```
#!/bin/sh

# Print environment variables for transmission's benefit
printenv > /etc/openvpn/myprovider/vpn.env


# Set up VPN routes
ip route add default via $route_vpn_gateway dev $dev table 10

ip rule add from $ifconfig_local/32 table 10
ip rule add to $route_vpn_gateway/32 table 10

ip route flush cache


# Add firewall rules
iptables -A INPUT -i $dev -p udp --dport 24328 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $dev -p tcp --dport 24328 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -o $dev -p udp --sport 24328 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o $dev -p tcp --sport 24328 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have configured to query dns servers on local eth0 network, it's possible.
Check /etc/resolv.conf, traffic is routed through default gateway to everywhere except for the local network.

Comment: I have added the VPN DNS servers to `resolv.conf`. There is a local IP adress in there as well. Even if I remove it, if I restart the computer, it's added again. Could it be the culprit, and any way to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: You can change your router dhcp service configuration...

Comment: I changed the router to link to the DNS servers, but it didn't resolve my problem unfortunately.